# jQuery Multiple Simple Rail Menu (not nested ul)

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

my css

```
ul{list-style-type:none;}
a{color:#666;text-decoration:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;}
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:underline;}

#navBar>ul>li{line-height:18px; }
#navBar>ul>li>a{padding:4px 8px}
#navBar>ul>li.active a{background:#eaeef0; color:#C00}

.depth0 { width:140px; float:left; height:150px; }
.depth1 { width:140px; float:left; display:none; }
.depth2 { float:left; display:none; }
```

my html

```
<div id="navBar">
  <ul class="depth0">
    <li><a rel="" href="#">menu1</a></li>
    <li><a rel="c1" href="#">menu2</a></li>
    <li><a rel="c2" href="#">menu3</a></li>
    <li><a rel="" href="#">menu4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="c1" class="depth1">
    <li><a href="#">menu2a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu2b</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="c2" class="depth1">
    <li><a rel="p1" href="#">menu3a</a></li>
    <li><a rel="p2" href="#">menu3b</a></li>
    <li><a rel="p3" href="#">menu3c</a></li>
    <li><a rel="p4" href="#">menu3d</a></li>
    <li><a rel="p5" href="#">menu3e</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="p1" class="depth2">
    <li><a href="#">menu3a_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu3a_2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu3a_3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu3a_4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu3a_5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".depth0").delegate('a','click',function(){
        var id= $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#navBar>ul>li").removeClass("active");
        $(".depth1, .depth2").hide();
        $("#"+id).slideDown(1000,'easeOutExpo');
        $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
    });

    $(".depth1").delegate('a','click',function(){
        var id= $(this).attr("rel");
        $(".depth1>li, .depth2>li").removeClass("active");
        $(".depth2").hide();
        $("#"+id).slideDown(1000,'easeOutExpo');
        $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
    }); 
    $(".depth2").delegate('a','click',function(){
        $(".depth2>li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

when click to link, must show active link (color,bg). (with easing menu effect) and open next depth menu ul. 3 level have now. i am writing some code but i dont know wich idea better for this. how can shorter writing this code? thnx for everybody. sorry for my english :)

[image]

jsFiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Hbq7r/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("body").on('click','a',function(){
   var id= $(this).attr("rel");

  if($(this).html().substr(0,7)=="menu3a_"){
  $("#p1").parent().children().eq(3).find("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");          
   return false;
    }

  if(id.substr(0,1)=="p"){
  $("#c2").parent().children().eq(2).find("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
  $("#p1").slideDown(1000,'easeOutExpo');  
        return false;
    }

    $(".depth1, .depth2").hide();
     $("#navBar>ul>li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
    if(id){
       $("#"+id).slideDown(1000,'easeOutExpo');
    }
});

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hbq7r/7/

Comment: thnx but this is not what i want.

Comment: you mentioned `shorter writing this code`..so i modified it..are you looking for something specific??

Comment: your code when click to depth 1 menu. closed depth1 and open to depth 2 i not want close depth1. for this is said.

Comment: i want short and better something. but this like my code long and not better. thnx for helping ;)

Comment: your code was not working as per your requirement.. but this is working..Anyways i will try to optimize it.